# Is it possible to force Android Studio to display all XML elements' properties on the properties pane?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning to use Android Studio 2.2. It is annoying to find that many XML elements' properties are not displayed on the properties pane. There must be a way to force AS to display them all.

For example:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="text text text"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
```

Corresponding properties pane:

[screenshot of properties pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLLBF.png)

Notice that `layout_weight` is missing from the pane. I remember the old version of AS used to display them all.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In this case, that would include some layout XML, plus a link to a screenshot showing what you are seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the icon above the properties pane depicting two opposite facing arrows to toggle between the new and old properties pane.

[image: Properties pane toggle]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.